# Problems loading .wav files with AudioKit

Tags: objective-c, audio, static-libraries, playback, audiokit

I am using a static library from AudioKit to playback audio samples for this music app i'm working on.  However, when following the tutorial for sample playback from AudioKit.io I am getting these errors.

`fieldTheory1[28918:3777755] Csound Error: INIT ERROR in instr 2: 
fieldTheory1[28918:3777755] Csound Error: mono loscil cannot read from stereo ftable
fieldTheory1[28918:3777755] Csound Error: 
fieldTheory1[28918:3777755] Csound Error:  - note deleted.  i2 had 1 init errors
fieldTheory1[28918:3777755] Csound Error:`

It appears to be a problem with the underlying Csound library that audiokit is built on top of.  This is however beyond my paygrade.  Has anyone experience with AudioKit or Csound who could point me in the direction of solving this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of just having to choose between AKMonoSoundFileLooper and AKStereoSoundFileLooper appropriately.  Trying just switching to the stereo version or saving your audio file as mono.